# Export SharePoint List to csv with Attachments included

Tags: sharepoint-online, export, attachments, azure, csv

I have a list in SharePoint Online with an attachments column containing related PDF files.

Right now when I export the list data to Excel or as a CSV (in order to transfer them to an Azure environment database), the attachments column just becomes a binary column showing whether or not the row contained an attachment, but I would like to retain the attachments themselves, or some way to easily link to them if they must be stored separately.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Is this for SharePoint Online or on-premise?

Comment: Sharepoint online

Comment: This should solve it for you. https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/spo-export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv/README.html?tabs=pnpps

Comment: You could try the PowerShell provided by Christoffer, it works.